# Reverse Proxy server for highly scalable, secure and available API

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I am looking at different Options for an reverse proxy server which can act as load balancer to develop a highly scalable and available and secure API.
so I am basically looking for your experiences to built such a robust architecture.
Can you please help me with the technology stack I should be using ?

Also wants to know should I select API Gateway(AWS) over reverse proxy servers

Comment: API gateway is primarily for serverless stacks. Use either the AWS application load balancer or the AWS network load balancer.

Comment: @jordanm API gateway is not limited in any way to serverless stacks.

Comment: @MarkB You're right, it can be pointed at NLB, but I don't think that's a common configuration. I edited my comment to say "primarily".

Comment: @Jordanm why don't you think that's common? I've seen that sort of configuration just as much in my career as I've seen it used for serverless stacks. Also the newer AWS HTTP API Gateways work with Application Load balancers. An API Gateway is a tool for exposing one or more backend APIs, with request and response translation, and request authorization. It is not "primarily" for serverless stacks.